# Entity Framework Core -- Upsert with guids generated in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, upsert

I have upsert working in an EFCore database by generating the keys database-side. For details, see [Use "Attach" as an Upsert in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48613068/use-attach-as-an-upsert-in-entity-framework-core).

Now for a new question -- is there a way to do it when the keys are Guids generated in C# code? Based on the docs, it seems like Attach and Update won't work. But is there something that will allow it?

If the answer is "No, you can't do that", please don't be afraid to say so.

Comment: I have the same question. Got your answer?

Comment: I gave up on doing it that way.